# Seperate Bio's between PhotoStack and StackOverlfow?

Tags: support, faq-suggestion

I'd like to place a link to my gallery in my bio, but I don't want it to replicate to my other stack exchange sites.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The bio on here is only pre-populated form StackOverflow (etc.) you can edit them and they will remain separate, as the do between, say, StackOverflow and ServerFault

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have updated my profile here, and it doesn't affect the stackoverflow profile.

This is a good question, as more people should be made aware of the fact that the profiles are separate. I looked through a bunch of profiles recently, and almost all were still the copy from stackoverflow.

Comment: I've tagged the question `[faq-suggestion]` for this reason.